# Adding windows minimize and maximize buttons?

Tags: window-management

Mostly in the title. Is there anyway to get minimize and maximize buttons and change their icons? Similar to OSX.

Answer (score 0):

You already have maximize button in every title bar (two arrows going from center to oposite directions), but minimize can be turned on in Window Controls, after installing elementary tweaks (the minize icon is something similar to usual download icon).

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks